# Logout on browser close not working

Tags: 8, cookies

I need to log out a user on browser close. I did following things but it's not working.

Copy default.services.yml to services.yml in the same directory and change the cookie_lifetime value 2000000 to 0.

```
cookie_lifetime: 0
```

and add the following line in settings.php

```
/**
 * Load services definition file.
 */
 $settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/default/services.yml';
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

> Update

After debuging a lot I found a weird issue, it is working on Firefox, Sarafi but not on Google Chrome.

Google Chrome showed "Session" in the expires column of session cookie. I was expecting some date/time. I later found out Chrome shows "Session" in expires when cookie time is less than the current time.

I am using google chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Was the cache was flushed out?

Comment: Yes, I ran drush cr all